# Differences between scanf & scanf_s

Tags: c

What's the difference between `scanf` and `scanf_s` in C. I'm using visual studio 13 and it keeps on giving me errors when i try to use `scanf`.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and add a bit of code showing how you are using scanf(), and the associated errors?

Comment: This is a Microsoft "extension" that's there to annoy you

Answer (score 0):

Both read formatted data from the standard input stream. The '`_s`' are Microsoft's 'secure' versions.

> These versions of **scanf, _scanf_l, wscanf, _wscanf_l have security
>   enhancements**, as described in [Security Features in the CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx):
>
> Many old CRT functions have newer, more secure versions. If a secure
>   function exists, the older, **less secure version is marked as
>   deprecated and the new version has the _s ("secure") suffix**.
>
> In this context, "deprecated" just means that a function's use is not
>   recommended; it does not indicate that the function is scheduled to be
>   removed from the CRT.
>
> The secure functions do not prevent or correct security errors;
>   rather, they catch errors when they occur. They perform additional
>   checks for error conditions, and in the case of an error, they invoke
>   an error handler (see Parameter Validation).
>
> For example, the strcpy function has no way of telling if the string
>   that it is copying is too big for its destination buffer. **However, its
>   secure counterpart, strcpy_s, takes the size of the buffer as a
>   parameter, so it can determine if a buffer overrun will occur. If you
>   use strcpy_s to copy eleven characters into a ten-character buffer,
>   that is an error on your part; strcpy_s cannot correct your mistake,
>   but it can detect your error and inform you by invoking the invalid
>   parameter handler.**

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Comment: Note: `scanf_s()` is in C11 spec in Annex B (informative section) and K (normative).